# Create a new column by concatenating two others with string formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code to concatenate two columns into a new one:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'name': ['Tomek', 'Jacek', 'Placek'],
    'surname': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['fullname'] = df['name'] + ' ' + df['surname']
print(df)

# output:
#    name surname  fullname
# 0   Tomek       A   Tomek A
# 1   Jacek       B   Jacek B
# 2  Placek       C  Placek C
```

However, I need to use string formatting instead:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'name': ['Tomek', 'Jacek', 'Placek'],
    'surname': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['fullname'] = f"{df['name']} {df['surname']}"
print(df)
```

But then the output is:

```
#     name surname                                           fullname
# 0   Tomek       A  0     Tomek\n1     Jacek\n2    Placek\nName: n...
# 1   Jacek       B  0     Tomek\n1     Jacek\n2    Placek\nName: n...
# 2  Placek       C  0     Tomek\n1     Jacek\n2    Placek\nName: n...
```

How can I use string formatting and still have the output like the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to use string formatting instead

Use `zip()` and then list comprehension

```
df['fill_name']=[f"{a} {b}" for a,b in zip(df.name,df.surname)]
print(df)
```

---

```
     name surname fill_name
0   Tomek       A   Tomek A
1   Jacek       B   Jacek B
2  Placek       C  Placek C
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this without list comprehension:

- [`pandas.Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas-series-str-cat) -  Concatenate strings in the Series/Index with given separator.

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'name': ['Tomek', 'Jacek', 'Placek'],
    'surname': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['fill_name']= df.name.str.cat(df.surname,sep=" ")
print(df)
```

O/P:

```
     name surname fill_name
0   Tomek       A   Tomek A
1   Jacek       B   Jacek B
2  Placek       C  Placek C
```